# Cannot connect to tfsexpress

Tags: tfs

So first of all im not sure witch of these softwares does this i have a TFS express server for myself so i can do version control while not using internet services Like Github or VSTS. i also have Teamcity for autobuilds but when i want to connect to my tfs server outside of my network i use correct external ip (lets call it xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port) port is correct one that i set in the router to lead to correct port and ip in network. When i enter it starts loading and it actaly opens a login window but when i log in it redirects me direcly to internal ip and with that it fails.

additional info: I'm configuring TFS both with my internal IP and External IP. When i set public URL to external IP it works with outside my network but not inside my network

Comment: This question has nothing to do with IIS Express, so don't use wrong tags.

Comment: sory Lex i just found out it is the problem with tfsexpress and more specificly wiht public URL. but that now gets me even more problems

Comment: now i can access from outside but not from inside

Comment: When you say from inside, did you just mean the same domain of your machine and TFSExpress server, could you explain more clearer? Besides, what's the detail error are you getting?

Comment: Thats ment inside the local network aka. My personal lan